# I can't install or run beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, windows, beautifulsoup, python-3.5, f-string

I was trying to install beautifulsoup using pip and then there was a message that asked me to update pip so i did then when i run the code with beautiful soup it gives me a syntax error here is the code:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxCSO.png]

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

and the error that appears on the command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tasnem\Desktop\py4e\Course 3\week4\urllinks.py", line 6, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\Tasnem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .builder import (
  File "C:\Users\Tasnem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Users\Tasnem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 12, in <module>
    import soupsieve
  File "C:\Users\Tasnem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\soupsieve\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import css_parser as cp
  File "C:\Users\Tasnem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\soupsieve\css_parser.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "C:\Users\Tasnem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\soupsieve\util.py", line 59
    f"'{func.__name__}' is deprecated. {message}",
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: "f-string" support was added in 3.6, you just need a newer Python (Python35 implies 3.5) https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below for install BeautifulSoup4 on your system

**How to Install BeautifulSoup4 on Windows Operating Systems**

1- You can check your Python version with the following command:

`python3 --version`

2- You can install pip on Windows by [downloading the installation package](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), opening the command line and launching the installer. You can install pip via the CMD prompt by running the following command.

`python get-pip.py`

3- You may need to run the command prompt as administrator. Check whether the installation has been successful by typing.

`pip --version`

4- To install BeautifulSoup4, run the following command from the command prompt.

`python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

I use python -m pip to execute pip using the Python interpreter I specify as Python. Doing this helps avoid ImportError when we try to use a package installed with one version of Python with a different version. You can use the command which python to determine which Python interpreter you are using.

**How to Install BeautifulSoup4 on Mac Operating Systems**

Open a terminal by pressing `Command (⌘) + Space Bar` to open the Spotlight search. Type in `Terminal` and press `Enter`. To get pip, first ensure you have installed Python3:

`python3 --version`

`Python 3.10`

Download pip by running the following curl command:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

The curl command allows you to specify a direct download link. Using the -o option sets the name of the downloaded file.

Install pip by running:

`python3 get-pip.py`

From the terminal, use pip to install BeautifulSoup4:

`python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

**How to Install BeautifulSoup4 on Linux Operating Systems**

All major Linux distributions have Python installed by default. However, you will need to install pip. You can install pip from the terminal, but the installation instructions depend on the Linux distribution you are using. You will need root privileges to install pip. Open a terminal and use the commands relevant to your Linux distribution to install pip.

*Installing pip for Ubuntu, Debian, and Linux Mint*

`sudo apt install python-pip3`

*Installing pip for CentOS 8 (and newer), Fedora, and Red Hat*

`sudo dnf install python-pip3`

*Installing pip for CentOS 6 and 7, and older versions of Red Hat*

`sudo yum install epel-release`

`sudo yum install python-pip3`

*Installing pip for Arch Linux and Manjaro*

`sudo pacman -S python-pip`

*Installing pip for OpenSUSE*

`sudo zypper python3-pip`

**BeautifulSoup4 installation on Linux with Pip**

Once you have installed pip, you can install BeautifulSoup4 using:

`python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

**Installing BeautifulSoup4 Using Anaconda**

First, to create a conda environment to install bs4.

`conda create -n bs4 python=3.10`

Then activate the bs4 container. You will see “bs4” in parentheses next to the command line prompt.

`source activate bs4`

Now you’re ready to install BeautifulSoup4 using conda.

Anaconda is a distribution of Python and R for scientific computing and data science. You can install Anaconda by going to the [installation instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/). Once you have installed Anaconda and created your conda environment, you can install BeautifulSoup4 using the following command:

conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4

**Check BeautifulSoup4 Version**

Once you have successfully installed BeautifulSoup4, you can check the version of it. If you used pip to install BeautifulSoup4, you can use pip show from your terminal.

`python3 -m pip show beautifulsoup4`

> Name: beautifulsoup4
>
> Version: 4.11.1
>
> Summary: Screen-scraping library

ref. https://researchdatapod.com/python-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-bs4/

Answer (score 0):

I tried the python code, it works great.
my installations are as follows: pip 22.0.4, python 3.10

Comment: when i ask for the pip version (pip --version) it gives me error!

Comment: I also tried to delete pip and reinstall it but it doesn't work too

Comment: I made worked your code correctly, I'm thinking you're still having trouble with about BeautifulSoup installation. You can find the details in my next reply.